# Is there an R function that allows you to plot all columns of a dataframe on the same graph?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 17 rows and 120 columns. I would like to plot each column on the same scatterplot, with x-axis being indexed 1-17. For obvious reasons I would prefer not to use the lines() function 119 times to overlay each column onto the graph.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In `ggplot2` this would be done by first reshaping the data. data %>% pivot_longer(-row) %>% ggplot(aes(row, value, color = name)) + geom_point()` but from a visualization perspective you may need to do something else if you want to make 120 different series distinguishable from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `matplot(df, type = "l")` to get you going?